# IntelliJ IDEA does not open with idea64.exe but opens with idea.bat

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a user of IntelliJ IDEA, and it used to work properly.
Yesterday, I removed Visual Studio 2019 from my laptop, and also some program files named 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable ...'.
Then I installed Visual Studio Code.

Suddenly, when I double click the icon of IntelliJ IDEA, the opening screen doesn't appear at all, and nothing happens. I checked the operations going on, and there was nothing.
This was the same when I clicked idea64.exe (my laptop is Windows 10, 64 bits)
But when I tried idea.bat, the cmd opened with the following error, and IntelliJ opened properly.

---

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020-09-30 16:40:07,217 [   1749]   WARN - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - The registry key 'ide.cache.screen.insets' accessed, but not loaded yet
2020-09-30 16:40:07,229 [   1761]   WARN - pi.util.registry.RegistryValue - The registry key 'ide.insets.cache.timeout' accessed, but not loaded yet

---

What's the problem and solution to this? How can I open IntelliJ IDEA properly by only clicking the icon that leads to idea64.exe?

Comment: Same here, I don't think it has anything to do with installing or removing other programs. Usually, the problem corrects itself after you have started IJ via the bat file.

Comment: Well, I can start IJ via the bat file, but that doesn't seem to correct the problem... :(

Comment: it may be caused by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184029.

“This is caused by Windows' Exploit protection, by the Mandatory ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization), to be exact. This is off by default on Windows, but can be changed. If you want to keep Mandatory ASLR on by default, you will have to add an override for idea.exe or idea64.exe that disables Mandatory ASLR for the executable”

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as what you said. I run the idea64.exe as administrator mode, it can be launched correctly. Very confuse me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31147969)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the agent jar file under the Jetbrains of the Program Files.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

In my case I originally installed Intelli in my windows machine user account.  When I log using that account I have no issues.  I've since then created a new domain user account on my machine.  When I logged onto that account and tried to access the Intellij IDE that's when I observed the same issues that Choi had.  I was able to start the IDE if I ran it as administrator. I went to the folder where the IDE was installed and gave myself full permissions.  When I did this, I got further along, but I got some issues accessing some dll in the AppData directory.  It might have been the AppData directory for the user account that the IDEA was originally installed with (I don't recall for sure). If it was the other user account that certainly explains why the IDE might have issues trying to access that dll.  The short of it is that I came to the conclusion that trying to fix the problem by correcting permission issues seems to be problematic.  I opted to just reinstall the Intellj IDEA again. In my case there was a newer version of the IDE available, so I would have been doing that anyway.

Choi's case seems to occur for some other reason than my situation.  It's certainly baffling to think that uninstalling a non-related product would affect on how the Intellij IDE works. Removing the MC VC++ Redistributable should not have any effect on how the Intellj IDE starts up. I think those activities are not related as to why your Intellij IDEA won't start.  From my experience, I've learned that file permissions issue can cause the observed symptoms.  Perhaps in doing the delete of this non-related software, Choi unintentionally messed up some file or directory permission. At any rate, that's water over the dam. My suggestion would be to reinstall the Intellj IDE.